# creating vm fail if vm type is different than other VMs in the Virtual Network

Tags: azure

My Azure configuration:

Virtual Network: VN

VN suppose to contain 3 virtual machines

1. *2 of type DS2*
2. *1 of type A3*

After creating the first 2 successfully (both under the same `virtual network` and with the same `resource-group`) i'm unable to create the 3rd vm.

The error i'm getting:

```
Unable to upgrade the deployment. The requested VM size 'Large' may not be 
available in the resources supporting the existing deployment. 
Please try again later, try with a different VM size or smaller number of
role instances, or create a deployment under an empty hosted service with a
new affinity group or no affinity group binding
```

When creating the vm i'm using different `Storage account` - `Standard-GRS`
As opposed to the one i'm using for the first 2 VMs: `Premium-LRS`

--- EDIT ---

All Vms are intended to run under the same Cloud Service. The first 2 are of types `DS2`, the 3rd one that i'm trying to create is of type `A3`

Comment: When creating the third VM, is that VM in the same cloud service as the other two, or into its own cloud service? Also: Is the third VM the A-series VM (with the first two being DS series)? Please edit your question to clarify how these VMs are spread across different cloud services (and yes, I understand you're dropping all of the VMs into the same vnet).

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for your comment. updated the question

Comment: One more clarification point: Are you deploying "classic" VMs or using the new ARM-based deployment scripts?

Comment: currently classic - from the new azure portal. using the *service management task*

Answer (score 1):

So... a cloud service is allocated to a specific compute cluster, and that particular cluster may support only a subset of available virtual machine types.

It's entirely possible that, based on the original VM size for the very first VM created, your cloud service ended up on a cluster which doesn't have A-series support. This is fairly easy to check via the portal (and I think a bit easier to check in the "classic" portal, as you get a simple dropdown with machine sizes, when adding a new VM to an existing cloud service - and the classic portal is unavailable to use with ARM-based deployments, hence my comment to your question).

Assuming there are no A-series VM sizes in that cluster, you still have the ability to create a new cloud service, in the same virtual network as your original cloud service, to hold your A-series VMs. You'd still have the ability for your VMs to communicate with each other directly (since they'd be on the same vnet).

For a bit more info: A colleague of mine wrote [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2014/11/11/azure-a_2d00_series-and-d_2d00_series-consistent-performances-and-size-change-considerations.aspx) which includes details around clusters and VM types.

Comment: the issue is that i am able to chose the A-series VM from the dropdown..I will try your suggested idea of creating another cloud service.